# firefox ignores background-size css

Tags: firefox, css

Trying to scale an image down using the background-size CSS rule but seems to be ignored with Firefox 3.5

**CSS**

```
.privatejoker {
    background: aqua url("../styles/images/home-privatejoker.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 365px 341px;
    height:341px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    margin-top: -6px;
    }
```

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Comment: Check here for browser support for background-size: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#Notes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`background-size` was added to Firefox 3.6, however the `-moz` vendor prefix was required.

Since version 4, it is no longer required. If you want to support Firefox 3.6 too, include the vendor prefix in addition to the normal property.

[Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph) provides a good link for [further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#Notes) at MDN.

Answer (score 1):

`background-size` will only work in FF4 + see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size for earlier FF version workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the sizes in the percentage format

```
background-size:100% 70%;
100% is the width 
70% is the height
```