# Resize background image with background-size, fails in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have an icon before my links, and I set this image as a background to my a-tags:

```
a {
    background: url('../../images-1/pil.png') left center no-repeat;
    background-size: 8px auto; // This is the real width of the image
}
```

In some places I want smaller icons, and I want to resize the background image using:

```
a.small {
    background-size: 5px auto;
}
```

In Firefox (and IE9), this results in a cropped image, even though it gets smaller. In Chrome and Safari it works as expected. Is this a bug in Firefox and how can I get around this? FF version is 28.0.

[image: example picture]

Comment: possible duplicate of [firefox ignores background-size css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873516/firefox-ignores-background-size-css)

Comment: Please read my question before suggesting duplicates. It's NOT about FF ignoring background-size.

Comment: Correct, sorry. In any case - I always choose not to rely on browser resizing/cropping/etc. My approach is to have multiple images with different sizes, if needed. Recommend you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this for more compatibility

```
a.small {
    background-size         : 5px auto;
    -webkit-background-size : 5px auto;
    -moz-background-size    : 5px auto;
    -o-background-size      : 5px auto;
}
```